# Wordpress Social Login not appearing on Registration Page

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, authentication

I've installed the 'Wordpress Social Plugin' on my website to allow people to register/login to the website using Facebook oAuth. The plugin works and appears on the login page but I'm unable to get it to appear on the registration page. The plugin suggests adding the following line of code to the page that we would like to require the option:

```
<?php do_action( 'wordpress_social_login' ); ?>
```

I've tried adding it to the 'wp-login.php'
as  well as to includes/general-template.php - This caused it to appear twice on the login page.

Confusion!

Comment: It's not a good idea to add it to wp-login.php. Adding any code to the Wordpress core files is a risk and will be overwritten when Wordpress is updated anyway.

Comment: Ah i see thanks - completely new to WP (if that wasn't already obvious)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, and providing your theme supports it, it might be a good idea to try to use a sidebar or widget area to output the plugin's content.

If not you can put the do_action(); code into the theme file that is rendering the page.

It's impossible to give any acute answers without seeing some code though. :)